# Function to print dataframe, that uses df name as an argument

Tags: python, pandas

In function, I can't use argument to define the name of the `df` in `df.to_csv()`.

I have a long script to pull apart and understand. To do so I want to save the different dataframes it uses and store them in order. I created a function to do this and add the order number 01 (`number_of_interim_exports`) to the name (from argument).

My problem is that I need to use this for multiple dataframe names, but the `df.to_csv` part won't accept an argument in place of `df`...

```
def print_interim_results_any(name, num_exports, df_name):

    global number_of_interim_exports
    global print_interim_outputs
    if print_interim_outputs == 1:
        csvName = str(number_of_interim_exports).zfill(2) + "_" +name
        interimFileName =  "interim_export_"+csvName+".csv"
        df.to_csv(interimFileName, sep=;, encoding='utf-8', index=False)

        number_of_interim_exports += 1
```

Comment: what do you mean by "won't accept an argument in place of df"?

Comment: I want it to take the df_name argument from the function and use this as the name for the df in df.to_csv(...       So print_interim_results_any(a_name, 1, use_this_df) =>   use_this_df.to_csv(...

Comment: Please, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Why not just pass the relevant dataframe to the function instead of passing its name? After accepting the dataframe as a variable called `df`, your function could then execute `do.to_csv()` to save that dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I think i just screwed something else up: this works fine:

```py
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({1:[1,2,3]})


def f(frame):

    frame.to_csv("interimFileName.csv")

f(df)
```